# How to read indexes from IndexReader in Lucene?

Tags: indexing, lucene

I am learning Lucene and I created an index file. This file has some repeated indexes an i want to delete them so I want to read every index and compare them with the rest using searches in Lucene but I don't know how to retrieve every index from the file and use it for doing the search.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to get IndexReader's documents and iterate them searching by label and then search using the value of every label.